KalmanNet, Machine Learning
I want to rebuild this machine learning structure, a KalmanNet. Machine Learning Structure KalmanNet. I have problems with the pointwise multiplication.
This is my code:
class MB_KalmanNet_GRU(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, F, in_gru, hidden_gru):
        super().__init__()
        self.F = F

        self.FC11 = nn.Linear(6, in_gru).to(device)
        self.GRU1 = nn.GRU(in_gru, hidden_gru).to(device)
        self.FC21 = nn.Linear(hidden_gru,  9).to(device)

    def forward(self, est, h_0, track_first):
        track_total = torch.empty(est.shape).to(device)
        track_total[0, :,: ] = track_first[0, :, :]
        pred_prev = track_first[0, :, :]
        h = h_0.clone()

        for i in range(1, est.shape[0]):
            pred = track_total[i-1, :,: ].unsqueeze(0) @ self.F.T

            delta_y = est[i, :, :] - pred
            delta_x = pred_prev - track_total[i-1, :,: ].unsqueeze(0)
            pred_prev = pred

            input_KGain = torch.cat((delta_y, delta_x), dim=2)
            into_gru = self.FC11(input_KGain)
            outta_gru, h = self.GRU1(into_gru, h)
            KGain = self.FC21(outta_gru)

            KGain_matrix = torch.reshape(KGain, (est.shape[1], 3, 3))
            innovation = torch.bmm(KGain_matrix, delta_y.squeeze(0).unsqueeze(2))
           
            track_total[i, :, :] = pred[0, :, :] + innovation.squeeze(2).unsqueeze(0)

        return track_total

I have problems with the section
           innovation = torch.bmm(KGain_matrix, delta_y.squeeze(0).unsqueeze(2))

If delta_y is just a tensor the gradients are calculated correctly. Also if I add KGain_matrix and delta_y.squeeze(0).unsqueeze(2) everything works fine. Only when multiplication is performed the gradients are not correctly calculated anymore. Instead, they are NAN.
I tried different structures and they work, just the multiplication which I need doesn't work.

Without all the code to reproduce it, I am not able to determine the problem. However, note torch.bmm does have some particular requirements under the hood. For example:

Non-initialization of tensors could be a problem, try torch.zeros_like(est).to(self.device)
Check dimensions: squeeze(0) seems redundant and could have unintended consequences, e.g., if batch is 1
Overflow intermediates: check inputs are small enough, since any norm throughout the process could lead to an overflow

assert not torch.isnan(KGain_matrix).any(), "NaNs in KGain_matrix"
assert not torch.isnan(delta_y).any(), "NaNs in delta_y"
You can try manually unrolling the batch to see if there are still problems.
Note on (2) above: I'm not sure why you have hard coded "3"s, but I deduced from your code (assuming the dimension of est is t = time, b = batch_size, f = feature_size):

dim[est] = t x b x f
dim[delta_y] = dim[pred] = dim[pred_prev] = dim[delta_x] = b x f
dim[delta_y.squeeze(0).unsqueeze(2)] = b x f x 1
dim[KGain_matrix] = b x 3 x 3

Since innovation is a matrix multiply, therefore I presume f = 3, but would be good to parameterize it to make sure there are no errors.
